# How to get the position of touched Item row in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, position, event-listener, listviewitem

**I want to get the position of the item which i have clicked.**

**Please Suggest me the same.**

**I have implemented the `ontouchItemListener` like this:**

**Please refer below code.**

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create RecyclerItemClickListener which implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}
```

Use this in activty

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {


                }
            })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlin form of @gokul-gowda's answer is:

```
class RecyclerItemTouchListener(
context: Context,
val listener: (view: View, position: Int) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

var mGestureDetector: GestureDetector = GestureDetector(context, object :
    GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return true
    }
})


override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val childView = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y)
    if (childView != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        listener.invoke(childView, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }
    return false
}

override fun onTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent) {
    //TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) {
    //TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

}
```